# Maintaining state in a HIVE query

Tags: caching, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I wrote a user-defined-function (UDF) that returns true iff the input  point (x,y,z) is on plane P.

The function `IsOnPlane` gets the `x,y,z` coordinates  of a point, and an index of the plane id `P` as an input.

For example, if P is the plane spanned by {(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)} then :

`IsOnPlane(0,700,2,   P)=TRUE` and `IsOnPlane(1,2,3,  P)=FALSE`

The planes are represented as the coefficient of the plane equation:
`Ax+By+Cz+D=0`

In order to implement the `IsOnPlane` function, I am using a different representation of plane (spanning vectors).

Is there a way to do the conversion once and store it in memory, and then use it to evaluate the return value of the function each time the UDF is called ?